# Thymeleaf th:text How to add static text to dynamic value

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Started with Thymeleaf and have one question. I have iteration with

```
<tr th:each="it,row  : ${res.answers}">
 <td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" th:text="${row.count}">
   1
 </td>
 <td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" th:text="${it.question}">
   Value1
 </td>
 <td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" th:text="${it.correctAnswer}">
   col2
   <a href="" th:onclick="'showExplanation(\'' + ${it.comment} + '\');'">
     <sup>Explanation</sup>
   </a>
 </td>
 <td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" th:text="${it.answer}">
   col3
 </td>
</tr>
```

The line with `${it.correctAnswer}` is one that should be formatted as following:

*If and only if there is not empty String in `${it.comment}` then it should be appended superscripted string "Explanation" and when we click this string some Javascript function is called.*

My solution above obviously didn't work, but is there any way to add some static html code to dynamic value generated by Thymeleaf at runtime.

What I am trying to do is :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you require to concat text to link, to do it simply change your html from:

```
<td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" th:text="${it.correctAnswer}">
 col2
 <a href="" th:onclick="'showExplanation(\'' + ${it.comment} + '\');'" >
  <sup>Explanation</sup>
 </a>
</td>
```

to

```
<td th:class="${row.even}? 'even' : 'odd'" >
 <span th:text="${it.correctAnswer}">col2</span>
 <a href="" th:if="${it.comment}!=''" th:onclick="'showExplanation(\'' + ${it.comment} + '\');'">
  <sup>Explanation</sup>
 </a>
</td>
```

This should display comments link when there are some.

Comment: David it worked. I had to add missing double quotation and then it worked. Thanks